# Bulk export from Teradata using python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is there a way to do a bulk export to CSV file from Teradata DB using SqlAlchemy Python package ?

Below is the code which is taking long time for 0.2 million records, and i have more than 5 million records.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

username = 'username'
password = 'pass#word'
host = 'hostname'
query = 'select * from databaseName.tablename;'

link = 'teradata://'+ username +':'+ password +'@'+host+'/'+'?driver=Teradata'
td_engine = create_engine(link)
result = td_engine.execute(query)
for r in result:
    print r
```

I am getting above print result as below:

```
(Decimal('29674'), u'1-20I6-32-AA', u'N/A', u'1-21LE-5126~SA-SW', u'SEP-21-2009', u'JAN-23-2008', u'N/A', u'AA', None, None, 
None, u'N/A', u'N/A', None, None, u'32211ZA21N', u'1-20I6-1123~AK~DS', 
u'QW231-AA11+2976891+2QQ11', u'2009-11-21 00:00:00', u'Installed', datetime.datetime(2011, 2, 15, 12, 1, 3), None, None, u'AA2', u'1-221', None)
```

Can we do something to get data in text form, which can be used directly such as `29674, 1-20I6-32-AA, N/A, 1-21LE-5126~SA-SW, SEP-21-2009, JAN-23-2008`

Comment: How long is a 'long time', and how often do you need to do this?

Comment: It takes around 5-7 minutes for 0.2 millions. As of now it is once a day.

Comment: So you are looking at 3 hours tops for the 5 million records. How often do you need to do this? if only once, can you wait for 3 hours?

Comment: Its once every day but 3 hours is quite long, i was wondering if there is some bulk export functionality available.

Comment: Agreed, for a daily task, you want to polish it a bit.

Comment: In postgresql, using pandas and SqlAlchemy, we can use `to_csv` to export as bulk and that was pretty quick. If similar to that can be done in teradata ?

Comment: I am afraid I have no idea.